# Can the result set of one sql query be used in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, select

I have two tables in mySQL db (photoentry and member). When the user logs in, I retrieve all there user details from the member table based on the email they used to login.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE email='"+email+"'";
```

and displayed the results like so:

```js
<td><b>Member ID: </b></td><td><input type="text" name="id" value="<%=resultSet.getString("id")%>"/> ></td>
```

I want to use this member ID to retrieve the photoentry associated with the user. I have tried

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM photoentry p where (SELECT id from member m WHERE p.m_ID = m.id AND email='"+email+"'";
```

How can I retrieve the photoentry associated with the member using the result set of the original query? (I am using JSP)

Comment: jsp also supports prepared statements to prevent SQL injection i advice you using them..

Comment: But looking into your last query it seams you are looking for `EXISTS` keyword....  `... where EXISTS(SELECT 1 from member ..` But MysQL tends to optimize co-related subquery badly so most likely you better off rewritting that query into using a join... `photoentry p INNER JOIN member m ON p.m_id = m.id WHERE email = '<email>'`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
String sql = "
SELECT p.* FROM photoentry AS p
   INNER JOIN member AS m ON 
   p.member_id = m.id
        WHERE m.email LIKE '"+email+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
String sql = "
    SELECT * FROM photoentry AS p
        JOIN member AS m ON (p.member_id = m.id)
            WHERE m.email LIKE '"+email+"'";
```

Comment: "Supposing that you have a relation bettween those tables" he most likely has that relation he is trying to write a co-related subquery notice the `WHERE p.m_ID = m.id` part in the inner SQL.

Comment: Yep, I saw when I checked  that again :D